# How to extend fancyref for listings?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, fancyref

I use a [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) environment to format source code such as a JSON file.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:json-example},caption=A JSON example]
{
  "title" : "JSON specification",
  "author" : "Douglas Crockford",
  "mimeType" : "application/json",
  "published" : "July 2006",
  "reference" : "http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627"
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

To reference the listing from within the text I would like to use [fancyref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyref) as I use it does a good job for figures, tables, sections and so on. However, I noticed that it does not take care of listings.
From the [documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/bibref/fancyref.pdf) I managed to figure out how to define a basic extension as you can see in the MWE at the bottom of this question.

As you probably know `fancyref` adds some magic to floating enviroments such as figures and tables and for chapter, sections and so on. When a reference is located on another page, the refering text changes automatically.

```
chapter 1 on the following page
Chapter 1 on the previous page
ﬁgure 1 on the facing page
Figure 1 on the page before
```

How can I enhance the above extension to automatically provide those magic references?

---

Here is a MWE to test the behavior.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{listings}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------
% Listing extension for fancyref using the prefix "lst".
% ---------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{lst}

% Main format
\frefformat{main}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{%
\MakeUppercase{\freflstname}\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1#2%
}%
\Frefformat{main}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{%
\MakeUppercase{\Freflstname}\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1#2%
}%
\Frefformat{main}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{Listing~#1}
\frefformat{main}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{listing~#1}

% Vario format
\frefformat{vario}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{%
\MakeUppercase{\freflstname}\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1#2%
}%
\Frefformat{vario}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{%
\MakeUppercase{\Freflstname}\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1#2%
}%
\Frefformat{vario}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{Listing~#1 on page #2}
\frefformat{vario}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{listing~#1 on page #2}

\begin{document}

I want to refer to a \fref{lst:example-1} and to a \fref{lst:example-2}.

\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:example-1},caption=A first example]
{
  "name" : "Listing 1"
}
\end{lstlisting}

\pagebreak

\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:example-2},caption=A second example]
{
  "name" : "Listing 2"
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following things had to be corrected:

- The counterpart to the `vario` option (which is enabled by default) is named not `main` but `plain`.
- `\frefformat{plain}`, `\frefformat{vario}` and their uppercase variants should be defined only one time for `\fancyreflstlabelprefix` (a second definition simply overides the first), and they should be modelled on the proper respective definitions for other elements.
- `\frefformat{vario}` must use the first and *third* underlying argument (`#1#3`).
- `\freflstname` and `\Freflstname` must be defined for all document languages (in the example: english).
- Always use `\fancyrefdefaultspacing` instead of `~` (to which it points to by default).

---

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fancyref}% option `vario` is default
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{lst}

\fancyrefaddcaptions{english}{%
  \providecommand*{\freflstname}{listing}%
  \providecommand*{\Freflstname}{Listing}%
}

\frefformat{plain}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{\freflstname\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}
\Frefformat{plain}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{\Freflstname\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}

\frefformat{vario}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{%
  \freflstname\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1#3%
}
\Frefformat{vario}{\fancyreflstlabelprefix}{%
  \Freflstname\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1#3%
}

\begin{document}

I want to refer to a \fref{lst:example-1}, to a \fref{lst:example-2}, and to a
    \fref{lst:example-3}.

\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:example-1},caption=A first example]
{
  "name" : "Listing 1"
}
\end{lstlisting}

\clearpage

\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:example-2},caption=A second example]
{
  "name" : "Listing 2"
}
\end{lstlisting}

\clearpage

\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:example-3},caption=A third example]
{
  "name" : "Listing 3"
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very impressing! But hard to read from the documentation. Thank you very much.